# SQL is intermittently returning no data in response to a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I am trying to hunt down a bug in a SQL query but can't seem to get to the bottom of it.  The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) AS X,
    DAYOFWEEK(BT.DateCheckedIn) AS DayX,
    SUM(IR.QtyCheckedIn) AS C,
    AU.AdminUsername,
    AU.AdminFirstName,
    AU.AdminLastName,
    IF(BTE.ProdLogID IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') AS Exclude
FROM
    buying_issuesreceived IR
    JOIN buying_transactions BT ON IR.TransactionID = BT.TransactionID
    JOIN adminusers AU ON BT.CheckedInByAdminUserID = AU.AdminUserID
    LEFT JOIN log_production_bt BTE
        ON DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) = DATE(BTE.ProductionDate)
        AND BTE.ProductionSection = 'wtransactions'
        AND AU.AdminUsername = BTE.ProductionUsername
WHERE
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) BETWEEN DATE  '2018-09-24' AND DATE  '2018-09-30'
GROUP BY
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn),
    AU.AdminUsername
```

When this query is run, it has about a 50/50 chance of returning the correct data or returning nothing at all.  There is no error message.  I know, or rather should say, am pretty certain, that the LEFT JOIN is the culprit because when I delete it from the code I stop getting empty tables, but can't, for the life of me, figure out why this query would return inconsistent results in the first place.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the left outer join in your query. I'd prefer an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause in the select clause, but the left outer join should work just as fine. Maybe there is something wrong with the database? Try `REPAIR TABLE` or `mysqlcheck --repair` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html#rebuilding-tables-repair-table).

Comment: Usually it's an INNER JOIN that causes missing results in queries. It's hard for a LEFT JOIN to cause this issue.

Comment: Yeah.  It's a weird one. That's what pushed me to stack overflow.  I've passed this to every other coder here and to my boss and everyone is scratching their heads.  The database seems fine because we have a bunch of other queries calling these tables that work just fine.  It's just one small subset of queries of this type, which don't seem to have anything wrong with them, that are having issues.  Been banging my head against the wall all day.

Comment: What versions of MySQL, client & server? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a MySQL bug. As a workaround, you can use `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) AS X,
    DAYOFWEEK(BT.DateCheckedIn) AS DayX,
    SUM(IR.QtyCheckedIn) AS C,
    AU.AdminUsername,
    AU.AdminFirstName,
    AU.AdminLastName,    
    IF(EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM log_production_bt BTE
        WHERE 
            DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) = DATE(BTE.ProductionDate)
            AND BTE.ProductionSection = 'wtransactions'
            AND AU.AdminUsername = BTE.ProductionUsername), 'NO', 'YES') AS Exclude
FROM
    buying_issuesreceived IR
    JOIN buying_transactions BT ON IR.TransactionID = BT.TransactionID
    JOIN adminusers AU ON BT.CheckedInByAdminUserID = AU.AdminUserID
WHERE
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn) BETWEEN DATE  '2018-09-24' AND DATE  '2018-09-30'
GROUP BY
    DATE(BT.DateCheckedIn),
    AU.AdminUsername
```